# Open Corresponding Popups for Various buttons in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

My HTML file has a number of icon images (all images have the same class attribute) and the same number of HTML snippets that represent a modal/popup (they also have the same class name). The icons and the popup snippets always come in pairs and are generated dynamically which means the exact number of pairs is unknown. My HTML code looks like this -

```
<img src="/images/info_icon.gif" class="tooltip_icon" alt="sample">
<div class="tooltip_modal">
  <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
      <span class="close">&times;</span>
      <h5>Tooltip</h5>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
      <p>Sample text 1</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<img src="/images/info_icon.gif" class="tooltip_icon" alt="sample">
<div class="tooltip_modal">
  <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
      <span class="close">&times;</span>
      <h5>Tooltip</h5>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
      <p>Sample text 2</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<img src="/images/info_icon.gif" class="tooltip_icon" alt="sample">
<div class="tooltip_modal">
  <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
      <span class="close">&times;</span>
      <h5>Tooltip</h5>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
      <p>Some text 3</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Please note that the text for each modal is different. 
I want to create a logic in JavaScript where clicking on the icon opens the corresponding model. For example - Clicking the first icon should show "Sample text 1" , clicking the second icon should show "sample text 2".

Below is my JS code which (obviously) doesn't work:

```
var btn = document.getElementsByClassName("tooltip_icon");
var modal = document.getElementsByClassName("tooltip_modal");


// Get the <span> element that closes the modal
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

// When the user clicks the button, open the modal 
function displayModal(k) {
    modal[k].style.display = "block";
}

// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
function hideModal(k) {
    modal[k].style.display = "none";
}

for (var i=0,j=0; i<btn.length,j<modal.length; i++,j++) {

    btn[i].onclick = displayModal(j);
    span.onclick = hideModal(j);
    window.onclick = function(event) {
    if (event.target == modal[j]) {
        hideModal(j);
    }
}
}
```

What I am trying to do here is loop through all icons and modals and for every `icon[i]` I am trying to call `modal[j]`.

Jsfiddle code - https://jsfiddle.net/2orwct27/

Please help!
Thanks in advance

Comment: Put your tried code into the jsfiddle and share with us.

Comment: My question already has a link to jsfiddle code.

Comment: oops! Sorry! Correcting the URL now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay,

there are several problems in your code. I rewrote the whole code so you get an idea what was wrong in your code and how *your* solution may look like.

Keep in mind, what I wrote uses language features which not all browsers support. In modern browsers however it will run fine.

```js
function openWindow(modal) {
 modal.style.display = 'block';
 setTimeout(() => { document.addEventListener('click', closeModal); });
}

function closeWindow(modal) {
 modal.style.display = 'none';
 setTimeout(() => { document.removeEventListener('click', closeModal); });
}

function closeModal(e) {
 const modal = getModalRoot(e.target);
 if (modal) return;
 
 [].forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll('.tooltip_modal'), closeWindow);
}

function getModalRoot(element) {
 if (!element || !element.classList) return null;
 if (element.classList.contains('modal-content')) return element;
 return getModalRoot(element.parentNode);
}

[].forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll('.tooltip_icon'), (x, i) => {
 x.id = `opener${i}`; 
 const modal = x.querySelector(`#${x.id} ~ .tooltip_modal`);
 
 x.addEventListener('click', () => { openWindow(modal); }); 
 modal.querySelector('.close').addEventListener('click', () => { closeWindow(modal); });
});
```

```css
/* The Modal (background) */
.tooltip_modal {
    display: none; /* Hidden by default */
    position: fixed; /* Stay in place */
    z-index: 1; /* Sit on top */
    padding-top: 100px; /* Location of the box */
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%; /* Full width */
    height: 100%; /* Full height */
    overflow: auto; /* Enable scroll if needed */
    background-color: rgb(0,0,0); /* Fallback color */
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4); /* Black w/ opacity */
}

/* Modal Content */
.modal-content {
    position: relative;
    background-color: #fefefe;
    margin: auto;
    padding: 0;
    border: 1px solid #888;
    width: 80%;
    box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2),0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.19);
    -webkit-animation-name: animatetop;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 0.4s;
    animation-name: animatetop;
    animation-duration: 0.4s
}

/* Add Animation */
@-webkit-keyframes animatetop {
    from {top:-300px; opacity:0} 
    to {top:0; opacity:1}
}

@keyframes animatetop {
    from {top:-300px; opacity:0}
    to {top:0; opacity:1}
}

/* The Close Button */
.close {
    color: white;
    float: right;
    font-size: 28px;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
    color: #000;
    text-decoration: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.modal-header {
    padding: 2px 16px;
    background-color: #425563;
    border-bottom: 4px solid #ffd100;
    color: white;
}

.modal-body {padding: 10px 16px;}

.modal-footer {
    padding: 2px 16px;
    background-color: #5cb85c;
    color: white;
}

/* Tooltip icon*/
.tooltip_icon
    {
        padding-bottom: 4px;
        padding-left: 2px;
    }
```

```html
<img src="/images/info_icon.gif" class="tooltip_icon" alt="sample">
<div class="tooltip_modal">
  <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
      <span class="close">&times;</span>
      <h5>Tooltip</h5>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
      <p>Sample text one</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<img src="/images/info_icon.gif" class="tooltip_icon" alt="sample">
<div class="tooltip_modal">
  <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
      <span class="close">&times;</span>
      <h5>Tooltip</h5>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
      <p>Sample text 2</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<img src="/images/info_icon.gif" class="tooltip_icon" alt="sample">
<div class="tooltip_modal">
  <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
      <span class="close">&times;</span>
      <h5>Tooltip</h5>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
      <p>Some text 3</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

First of all I didn't change any HTML or CSS.

### What's different

Instead of looping thru all images and modal-elements and change there html, you could add an [EventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) for the images and each close-element.

For the functions to show and hide the modal now it get's the modal itself instead it's index.

In your code you check on click if the click target equals the model. If so it should close it. But in the comment in your code you wan't it the other way around. Because I guess this is the natural behavior this is the way it's implemented in my snipped.